# how to use onchange function for a selection field to fetch data into many2one? in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

Good morning all, i have a selection field in current model and many2one field from another model. when room type get changed i want to fetch only that type rooms into many2one field.I can do it when many2one field changed. Or can do any modifications in VIEW.xml file for filtering ?? Here is the code.

[image: Here is the picture]

```
class RoomInfo(osv.osv):
_name='room.info'
_rec_name='room_num'
_columns = {

    'room_num':fields.char('Room Number'),
    'room_type' : fields.selection([('1BHK','1BHK'),('3BHK','3BHK'),('2BHK','2BHK')],'Room type'),
    'status':fields.selection([('reserved', 'Reserved'),('vacant', 'Vacant')],'Status'),
    'fare':fields.float('Fare')

}

RoomInfo()  

class Hotel(osv.osv):
_name = 'book.room'

_columns ={

    'name' : fields.char('Customer name',required=True),
    'roomtype' : fields.selection([('1BHK','1BHK'),('3BHK','3BHK'),('2BHK','2BHK')],'Room type'),
    'room_num':fields.many2one('room.info','Room Number',required=True), 


        }

@api.one
@api.onchange('room_num')
def _on_change_nationality(self):
   self.country_code_lead = self.nationality_lead.country_code
   self.fare = self.room_num.fare
   self.room_type = self.room_num.room_type

Hotel()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write on change method for that,

simply apply domain on the field.

```
<field name="roomtype" />
<field name="room_num" domain="[('roomtype','=',roomtype)]" />
```